# Orchard CMS web services

Tags: web-services, content-management-system, orchardcms

Is it possible to implement RESTful webservices with Orchard CMS? The way I understand it from reading the documentation is by implementing a new module and rendering the views as json/xml/etc.

What if I wanted to expose all of Orchard's Admin abilities through a web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done it myself. I have used Orchard CMS and WebApi on separate projects though.
I do recall seeing a blog post explaining how to integrate [WebApi](http://wcf.codeplex.com/) with Orchard CMS.

If you are not familiar with WebApi you should check it out.

Here it is: [OrchardProject + WebApi = interesting](http://blogs.geniuscode.net/JeremiahRedekop/?p=565)

Comment: never heard of WebApi, but that is an interesting project. If Orchard is built on ASP.NET MVC I'd prefer to go with the tools already built in.

Answer (score 4):

Orchard is MVC. You would do that pretty much exactly the same way as with a regular MVC app. Only difference will be how you define your routes (implement IRouteProvider instead of adding them from global).